# Distribute .so file on linux?

Tags: c, linux, installation, shared-libraries

I have a shared library that my application needs (a .so) and I am wondering what is the best way to distribute it?

It's not something that can be apt-get installed and I need it in the LD path's in order to run the application.

Comment: If the target system have all dependencies, then just put it in a path that the dynamic run-time linker [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) looks in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the past I've needed to include a separate "launcher script" that the user would click on instead of clicking on the Linux executable directly.  The launcher script would set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the directory where the shared library was stored, and then launch the executable.  Here's the script, for reference (it assumes that the executable and the shared library are hidden away in a sub-folder named "bin", and that the executable's name is the same as the script's name except without the ".sh" suffix):

```
#!/bin/bash
appname=$(basename "$0" .sh)
dirname=$(dirname "$0")
cd "$dirname/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./$appname "$@"
```

Comment: Should that not be `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that if the program runs something else, the correct other library path is used?  Certainly, that's what I've always done in my analogues to your script.  Given that it is Linux, you're probably safe assuming `$0` has an absolute path for the script, but it is not actually a given on every platform.  Classically, `$0` contained just the basename of the program or script.

Answer (score 2):

Distribute it the same way you distribute the executable that depends upon it; bundle the two together.

If you didn't write the library, make sure you're complying with its license terms for redistribution.

Comment: But it doesn't pick it up if it is in the same directory, only if it is in `/usr/lib/` or another LD directory?